# Обратиться к элементу, который генерируется javascriptom

Tags: javascript, frontend

мне нужно создать функцию, которая вызывается при нажатии на блок, но поскольку этот блок генерируется через javascript следующий способ:

````
$('#delete').click(function(){
   alert('works');
 })``` не работает( 
Каким образом я могу обратиться к элементам через DOM?
````

Comment: вызовите этот код после добавления сгенерированного элемента

Comment: `$(document).on("click", "#delete", function() {` https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605509/4822490